# Sabre: Create OTA_AirPriceRQ for duplicate fare

Tags: sabre

How can I choose the right fare of duplicate fare (same fare basis and booking class but different base fare and rules)?

OTA_AirRulesRQ:

```
<OTA_AirRulesRQ ReturnHostCommand="true" Version="2.3.0" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10">
    <OptionalQualifiers>
    </OptionalQualifiers>
    <OriginDestinationInformation>
        <FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="03-08">
            <DestinationLocation LocationCode="SGN"/>
            <MarketingCarrier Code="VN"/>
            <OriginLocation LocationCode="VII"/>
        </FlightSegment>
    </OriginDestinationInformation>
    <RuleReqInfo>
        <FareBasis Code="LAP5VNF1"/>
    </RuleReqInfo>
</OTA_AirRulesRQ>
```

OTA_AirRulesRS:

```
<OTA_AirRulesRS xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" Version="2.3.0">
    <stl:ApplicationResults status="Complete">
        <stl:Success timeStamp="2022-02-13T00:14:56-06:00">
            <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                <stl:HostCommand LNIATA="222222">RDVIISGN08MARLAP5VNF1-VN</stl:HostCommand>
            </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
        </stl:Success>
    </stl:ApplicationResults>
    <DuplicateFareInfo>
        <Text>VII-SGN       CXR-VN       TUE 08MAR22                     VND
THE FOLLOWING CARRIERS ALSO PUBLISH FARES VII-SGN:
BL EK H1 QH VJ
//SEE FQHELP FOR INFORMATION ABOUT THE NEW FARE DISPLAYS//
ALL FEES/TAXES/SVC CHARGES INCLUDED WHEN ITINERARY PRICED
SURCHARGE FOR PAPER TICKET MAY BE ADDED WHEN ITIN PRICED
VN-VNY/EC - ECONOMY CLASSIC
V FARE BASIS     BK    FARE   TRAVEL-TICKET AP  MINMAX  RTG
1  ¤LAP5VNF1       L X  1242000 D31MY  T10MY  -/  -/  - 3000
2  ¤LAP5VNF1       L X  1306000 D31MY  T10MY  -/  -/  - 3000
3000*  TRAVEL MUST BE DIRECT</Text>
    </DuplicateFareInfo>
</OTA_AirRulesRS>
```

The first fare (1242000) violates the BLACKOUT DATES rule and I must choose the second fare (1306000) to book.
How do I specify the right fare in OTA_AirBookRQ and OTA_AirPriceRQ?

Answer (score 1):

The published rules are the same so it doesn't matter which one you take.
The difference lies within the rule that will differentiate which one is being applied to the PriceQuote of the reservation.
The airlines publish the same tariff base with different values in order to be able to work with the benefits of the tariff families.